# Possible typo in math Linear Algebra textbook

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the section of my Linear Algebra textbook, it states the coefficient matrix $\lambda$I - A can be written in this form

\begin{pmatrix} \lambda-a_{11}&a_{12}&... -a_{1n}\\-a_{21}&\lambda - a_{22}&...-a_{2n}\\-a_{n1}&-a_{n2}&\lambda - a_{nn} \end{pmatrix}
  = 0

But the textbook states in one of the examples that the matrix A is

\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\0&0&1\\4&-17&8 \end{pmatrix}

but its coefficient matrix $\lambda$I - A is

\begin{pmatrix} \lambda&-1&0\\0&\lambda&-1\\-4&17&\lambda - 8 \end{pmatrix}

Should it not be $a_{12}$ be 1 instead of -1 in the coefficient matrix given the form stated initially? Or is there a typo in written form? The written form is shown that all entries ignoring the main diagonal and $a_{12}$ are negative and only $a_{12}$ is positive...

Comment: Actually $a_{12}$ should be shown with a negative since they are using the convention $(\lambda I - A)$.

Comment: Yes there's a *ttpo* and it should be $-a_{12}$.

Comment: in the first matrix you wrote, entry (1,2) should be $-a_{12}$ (instead of $a_{12}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a typo.  The typo is in the term $a_{12}$, which should be $-a_{12} = -1$.

I think your post has a typo too:

I think the term you were questioning is $a_{12}$ and not $a_{21}$.

Matrix entries are written $a_{rc}$ where $r$ is the row in which it appears, and $c$ is the column in which it appears.

Comment: Typoes everywhere. I'm sure you agree that the $(1,2)$ entry of $\lambda I-A$ is $-a_{1,2}$.

Comment: Ah yes! I also flipped my subscripts around. Fixed! Nice to know there was a typo. Usually I'm never right when it comes to arguing with math...